# html5 video - one video is playing while others not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

Currently I am working on html5 video and video format is in **MP4**.My code is below:

```
    <video id="vid" preload="auto" loop autoplay>
    <source src="path to video.mp4'; ?>" type="video/mp4">
    Your Browser doesn't support video.
  </video>
  <video id="vid1" preload="auto" loop autoplay>
    <source src="path to video1.mp4'; ?>" type="video/mp4">
    Your Browser doesn't support video.
  </video>
  <video id="vid2" preload="auto" loop autoplay>
    <source src="path to video2.mp4'; ?>" type="video/mp4">
    Your Browser doesn't support video.
  </video>
```

But the issue is that video which is having id `vid1` `vid2` is not playing on any browser. Although id `vid` is working on all browser.

I am playing that with the following script :

```
   $("#vid").ready(function(){
      document.getElementById("vid").play();
});
$("#vid1").ready(function(){
      document.getElementById("vid1").play();
});
$("#vid2").ready(function(){
      document.getElementById("vid2").play();
});
```

1st Video is working file.But other two are not.I have tried following too:

```
$("video").ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("vid").play();
        document.getElementById("vid1").play();
    document.getElementById("vid2").play();
});
```

What should be the possible reason for that ? There is no console error as well.

Comment: You have a syntax error in the `src` attributes of your videos - I'm not sure if you've just made a mistake here or if this mistake is in your actual code, too.

Comment: Its typo . It was not an issue.Though thanks for your time. Got the solution by clearing cache :)